# Babel throws a syntax error on arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to adapt [this code](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/component-demos/tables#sorting-amp-selecting) for a small project with React, but I'm having trouble, and I don't know how to fix this, because I don't know if this is the original code or my Babel that's buggy (like, missing a library or something), or if I can't because React.

So the thing is I had to adapt some functions because otherwise Babel would throw an unexpected token on them, i.e,

```
static propTypes = { // unexpected '='
  onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSelectAllClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  order: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

became

```
static get propTypes() {
    return {
        onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        onSelectAllClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        order: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }
}
```

and this:

```
handleRequestSort = (event, property) => { ... } // unexpected '='
```

became this:

```
handleRequestSort(event, property) { ... }
```

For my main issue, I replaced this:

```
createSortHandler = property => event => { // unexpected '='
    this.props.onRequestSort(event, property);
};
```

by this

```
createSortHandler(property) {
    return function (event) {
        this.props.onRequestSort(event, property);
    };
};
```

However, if I click on the arrow on the table that triggers the order's change, I get  `cannot read props of undefined`. Otherwise, I get `unexpected token '=', as written in my code.

So my question is the following: is the original code buggy, is it my babel or is it something else? I'm currently on a Rails base with webpacker, but i don't believe this is the reason why I have these issues.

Comment: Try to `return (event) => { …` from the method

Comment: The original code is not ES6, but a proposed syntax extension. It's not Babel that is buggy. You can easily put `this.handleRequestSort = (event, property) => …;` inside your constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the [`babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin to transform the class properties which is experimental syntax (hence the unexpected token `=`). Include that in Babel configuration if you would like to use class properties for `propTypes` and class property arrow functions. The second error, that `this.props` is undefined is because you're using a regular function which `this` doesn't refer to the component. Return an arrow function instead:

```
createSortHandler(property) {
  return (event) => {
    this.props.onRequestSort(event, property);
  };
};
```

Comment: I installed the plugin and recompiled the code, but if I try with the 'old' versions, I still get the unexpected '='

Comment: @Jaeger Did you add it to the configuration?

Comment: i didn't read through the whole documentation, so I didn't see it needed to be added, i felt dumb for a minute :D
Thank you, everything seems to work perfectly now, I can use the syntax they suggered!